# Error in adding postgis extension in postgresql 9.4.5 in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I had installed postgresql version 9.4.5 through ubuntu software center (ubuntu 15.04). When i try to add postgis extension by `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`It is raising an error

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so: undefined symbol: pj_get_spheroid_defn
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so: undefined symbol: pj_get_spheroid_defn
SQL state: XX000
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should to [install postgis from apt repo first](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS22UbuntuPGSQL95Apt): `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1`. [PostGIS - installation](http://postgis.net/install/)

Comment: It is already installed. When i run the above command i get postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 is already the newest version.